# How to generate no from 1 to 1000 randomly without using random class in java?

Tags: java

I want to generate array position from 1 to 1000 randomly using some mathematical formula and without `java.util.Random` class in Java. I want to generate same random series at client and server side. How can I do this?

Comment: Why is "without RANDOM class" a requirement here? Is it homework or is there any other reason?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: You definitely need to clarify your question - right now it's not clear what you want apart from "a random number that's not random".  In particular, you'll need to think about "how" random you want this to be - where your random seeds are coming from, and how they're securely shared between client and server.

Comment: so you want to generate sequence of random numbers and they must be same at client and server? Random with same seed will produce same sequences.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: If he wants to generate the same "random" number client-side, he can't use Java, I guess.

Comment: @axtavt i think there should be close option: "Explained in Wikipedia". the article has all needed information.

Comment: @Tim: why's that? It's perfectly possible to generate identical pseudo-random numbers in Java. Just use the same seed for the default `Random` implementation.

Comment: @Joachim: I was guessing that he's talking about a web client using JavaScript. I may be completely off the mark, though :)

Comment: @Tim, that would explain why he can't use Java's Random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client and server are presumably communicating with either other, the simplest way to implement this is just to have the server generate a random number in the usual way, and then transmit this random number to the client securely (e.g. through an HTTPS channel).

If you want the server and client to *independently calculate* this number, then:

1. It's not really random, by definition; and
2. It must depend on some other input in order to be repeatable (e.g. the MD5 hash of a particular file)
3. What do you hope to gain from this parallel calculation, rather than just transmitting a number which is guaranteed to match?

Comment: i want to pick up array position from 1 to 1000 which is not sequential and all array positions should used is there any formula to do this???

Answer (score 2):

If your real requirement is "*same random series at client and server*" the you can use Random with exactly same initial seed.

And actually java Random uses mathematical formula, and it's not truly random.

Example:

```
Random client = new Random(12345);
Random server = new Random(12345);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   assert client.nextInt() == server.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, without using the Random class, you could use the current time to generate a random number, then get it back in the 1-1000 range. Something like (crude, but hey...) :

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
long rand = time % 1000;
```

EDIT : didn't see the "same on client and server" part... Then the answer of Splix above using the random class with a given initial seed seems indeed like the way to go.

Comment: System.nanoTime() might be a better choice as you can call this 1000s of times in the same milli-second. ;)

Comment: true enough, I admit I never tried to generate random numbers without relying on java.util.Random :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following simple modulo randomiser.

```
public class SimpleRandom {
    private long seed;

    public SimpleRandom(long seed) {
        this.seed = seed;
    }

    public int nextInt(int n) {
        seed += 1111211111;
        return (int) ((seed >>> 8) % n);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SimpleRandom sr = new SimpleRandom(0);
        SortedSet<Integer> ints = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        while(ints.size() != 1000) {
            for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
                ints.add(sr.nextInt(1000));
            System.out.println("min: "+ints.first()+" max: "+ints.last()+" count: "+ints.size());
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
min: 1 max: 998 count: 500
min: 1 max: 999 count: 682
min: 1 max: 999 count: 807
min: 0 max: 999 count: 925
min: 0 max: 999 count: 1000
```